# window.location.reload(); fails unless coupled with an alert

Tags: javascript

In my MVC javascript, I have the following code:

```
addEvent(document.getElementById("mta"), 'keydown', function() {

    var keycode = event.which || event.keyCode;

    if (keycode == 27) {
        //alert(x);
        window.location.reload(true);
        return
    }

etc...
```

The idea is to clear all input when the user presses the escape key. This doesn't work unless the alert is un-commented. Browser is Firefox. WTH ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had early today a similar problem. One of the mistakes I can see is `event.keyCode`, which is depreciated right now, you can replace it with `event.key`.

I leave you the code that worked for me.

```
addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
    if (event.key === "Escape") {
        event.preventDefault();
        window.location.reload(true);
    }        
});
```

Comment: Thanks Manu. The solution was using the keyup event (as you did) rather than keydown.

Comment: @ALX Could you mark it as correct for the future people that could have the same problem to know which is the answer. Glad it worked